# how to set the context of another class from different class?

Tags: android, preferences

I have a main activity and a settings activity. The settings activity class is fired via intent when clicked on a menu item Settings. Now, i want to make sure the default values are set in the preferences so inside onCreate for MainActivity i call the following code. But the error is that the mainactivity context is not taken by the setDefaultValues method. I think it needs to context of Settings Activity. How can i pass in the correct context from MainActivity. In other words what should i put instead of this from main activity onCreate method.

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

UPDATE:

My Main Activity looks as follows: Here the important part is setDefaultValues where i am getting error on the this part. "this" is not acceptable there. When i set the default values inside the SettingsFragment or SettingsActivity class then it works fine so looks like i need to pass the context of SettingsActivity and not the MainActivity. Please help! Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);


    }
```

I have a different activity for settings

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
```

This is the error i am getting

[image]

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: `I think it needs to context of Settings Activity` This is wrong, any context is fine.

Comment: Please, provide more code to describe your thoughts

Comment: You must be calling this code from any thread. Make sure you are not doing and if doing, use 'MainActivity.this' instead 'this'

Comment: if you dont know the answer please dont vote down.

Comment: How about using `getBaseContext()` ?

Comment: it seems getBaseContext() method is inaccessible in MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

use application context and save values into prefereces with different name.

Answer (score 0):

ok i just resorted to doing the setting of default values in onCreate method of PreferenceFragment since it makes sense the values will be initialized when PreferenceFragment is created so i cannot set the default values before the creation of PreferenceFragment.